# Improve a parallelogram with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the following figure:

[image]

I modified the code of the answer of this question [Help to draw a trapezoid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286569/help-to-draw-a-trapezoid)

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, multi, tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,angles,quotes}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[my angle/.style={font=\scriptsize, draw, angle eccentricity=1.75, angle radius=3mm}]
      \node (a) [trapezium, trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, draw, thick, label=below:$b$, label=left:$a$] {};
        \draw [densely dashed] (a.north west) coordinate (a nw) -- (a nw |- a.south) node [midway,right] {$h$} coordinate (a1);
          \coordinate (a blc) at (a.bottom left corner);
           \pic [my angle, "$\alpha$"] {angle=a1--a blc--a nw};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

There are a couple of things to be improved.

1. How can the label $b$ be positioned midway?
2. How can the parallelogram be in the center of the picture? It appears to me that it is displaced to the top.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [`label=[<options>]<angle>:<text>`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/label) is an additional node that is placed in the `<angle>` direction of its parent node where the anchor of the label node is evaluated somewhat automatically by TikZ.

Besides a numerical number (like `60`) and the special angles `below` (= `270`), below left, … it also can be just the anchor of the parent node, here `bottom side` which specifies the halfway point of the bottom side.

Since TikZ interprets this as `240` (because it is at 240° from the parent node's center) we will need the label to explicitly use `anchor = north`.

Here I'm using `below` (which implicitly sets `anchor=north`) to place the label `inner ysep` (defaults to `.3333em`) away from the parent node before setting `inner ysep` to zero which solves your other problem. (An alternative solution could have used [`label distance`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/label:distance).)

---

The label adds `inner ysep` on both sides of the `b` to calculate the shape's border (the rectangle that would be drawn). This border also contributes to the bounding box which is why the bottom side of your picture is `inner ysep` farther away from ink than the top side.

Compare the gray one (only `anchor = north`) with the black one (`below=.3333em, inner ysep=0pt`):
[image]

---

I've added with `coordinate suffix = <suffix> at <anchor>` a shortcut to a label that might make it easier to declare coordinate aliases for anchors of a node.

I've also added `outer sep = +0pt` to the trapezium so that all anchor references lie on the border (and not on the outside of it).

Without:
[image]

With:
[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, angles, quotes}
\tikzset{
  coordinate suffix/.style args={#1 at #2}{
    % or: append after command =
    %        coordinate (\tikzlastnode\space#1) at (\tikzlastnode.#2)
    label={[name=\tikzlastnode\space#1,coordinate]#2:}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  my angle/.style={
    font=\scriptsize, draw, angle eccentricity=1.75, angle radius=3mm}]
\node (a) [trapezium, trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120,
           minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, draw, thick,
%           label={[anchor=north, draw, gray]bottom side:$b$},
           label={[below/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep},
                   inner ysep=+0pt]bottom side:$b$},
           label=left:$a$,
           coordinate suffix = blc at bottom left corner,
           coordinate suffix = nw  at north west,
           outer sep=+0pt,
           ] {};
\draw [densely dashed] (a nw) -- node [right] {$h$} (a nw |- a.south)
                                                    coordinate (a1);
%\coordinate (a blc) at (a.bottom left corner);
\pic [my angle, "$\alpha$"] {angle=a1--a blc--a nw};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the code and the tutorial level explanations!

Answer (score 4):

I think that something fundamental is being overlooked here... The squiggly lines of the first pic!

Just kidding `;)` But just for fun, I post here my "solution" that places manually the label `$b$` in the middle of the base by the means of a `\path`, and relative `[midway,below]` node, from the trapezium's `.bottom left corner` and `.bottom right corner`. You just have to know the names of the additional nodes associated with the `trapezium` shape (see the TikZ manual):

[image: trapezium shape nodes]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,angles,quotes,decorations,decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my angle/.style={font=\scriptsize, draw, angle eccentricity=1.75, angle radius=3mm},
  squigglyline/.style={decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=1pt,amplitude=0.15pt}}]
  \node (a) [trapezium, trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, draw, thick, label=left:$a$, outer sep=+0pt,squigglyline] {};
  \draw [densely dashed,squigglyline] (a.north west) coordinate (a nw) -- (a nw |- a.south) node [midway,right] {$h$} coordinate (a1);
  \coordinate (a blc) at (a.bottom left corner);
  \pic [my angle, "$\alpha$"] {angle=a1--a blc--a nw};
  \path (a.bottom left corner) -- (a.bottom right corner) node [midway, below] {$b$}; % place $b$ manually, knowing trapezium shape's nodes's names
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is the result (adjust the parameters of the `squigglyline` style to your liking):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think there is an abusing `node` (trapezium) here. Let's draw the simple figure as simple as it is.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[7]  
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=4;b=2.5;alpha=65;r=.4;}]    
\path 
(0,0) coordinate (A) +(alpha/2:.6) node[red]{$\alpha$}
(a,0) coordinate (B)
(alpha:b) coordinate (D)
($(B)+(D)-(A)$) coordinate (C)
($(A)!(D)!(B)$) coordinate (H)
;
\draw[red] (A)+(r,0) arc(0:alpha:r);
\draw[dashed] (D)--(H) node[midway,right]{$h$};
\draw[thick] (A)
--(B) node[midway,below]{$a$}
--(C)--(D)
--cycle node[midway,left]{$b$};
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\lipsum[8]
\end{document}
```

**Asymptote code:**

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
real a=4, b=2.5;   // 2 sides of the parallelogram 
real alpha=65;     // an angle of the parallelogram
pair A=(0,0),B=(a,0),D=b*dir(alpha);
pair C=B+D-A;
pair H=(D.x,0);
draw("$h$",align=E,D--H,gray+dashed);
draw(arc(A,.3,0,alpha),magenta);
draw(A--B--C--D--cycle,black+1pt);
label("$\alpha$",A,2.8dir(alpha/2),magenta);
label("$a$",A--B,S);
label("$b$",A--D,W);

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```